# Threading 2 functions

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to read a very slow sensor (1-wire) while still operating other functions. I've replaced the read sensors with a sleep of 3 sec. I'd like to understand if I can have below time concurrently print accurate time every second while the sensor (wait 3sec.) occurs. This threading concept is new to me.

```
import time
import threading
from tkinter import Tk

def events_every_second(): #update clock every second
    right_now = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")#("%H:%M:%S")
    print("time is now",right_now)
    root.after(1000, events_every_second)
def one_wire():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("one_wire loop")
    root.after(3010, one_wire)

root = Tk()

t_one_wire = one_wire()
thread_one_wire = threading.Thread(target = t_one_wire)
thread_one_wire.start()

t_ees = events_every_second
thread_ees = threading.Thread(target = t_ees)
thread_ees.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please edit to give your language & system. Explain your problem with this code & what it is doing that is OK. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [help]

Comment: Other than the answer, I'd like to thank you for providing a comprehensible minimal example detailing exactly what you were doing and what you want without being too large. If it were not for this, I would not have taken my time to answer the question.

Comment: @philipxy : this is a minimal reproducible example - it is just that the part the OP was not getting right - starting threads and mixing then with tkinter, would actually prevent the program to run at all.

Comment: @jsbueno The code might be all there but that's not all there is to a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `root.after(3010,one_wire)` this will cause your Tk GUI to hang for 3 seconds and don't update.

You want to create a new Thread for this function so it does not stop your Tk app.

```
def one_wire():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("one_wire_loop")
```

create a new thread for this function.

```
import threading

one_wire_thread = threading.Thread(target = one_wire, args = ())
one_wire_thread.start()
```

Note that the code above will only run your function once. you could create a wrapper function with a `while True:` in there to keep it running, in the wrapper function you could also check for condition to stop and break the function and thus stop the `one_wire` function. you could also do this in the `one_wire` function:

```
def one_wire():
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print("one_wire_loop")
        if {"condition to stop reading sensor"}:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the function that does the lenghty sensor read needs to be 
in a separate thread.
You can use a `queue.Queue` to obtain data from it -
in the example bellow I inserted the value fetching in the
`every_one_sec` function.

The  `every_one_sec` function is handled by Tkinter scheduling events -
no need to creat a thread for it.

Other than that, the most incorrect part in your code was doing a 
full call to `one_wire` before creating the thread in 
`t_one_wire = one_wire()` - and the fact that it would run also require
tkinter to call it back. Tkinter wants to run all its events in the same
thread - so this would lead to problems.

I hope the comments bellow are enough for a better comprehension

```py
import time
import threading
from queue import Queue, Empty
from tkinter import Tk


def some_ui_code():
    global stop_reading
    stop_reading = True

def events_every_second(): #update clock every second
    right_now = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")#("%H:%M:%S")
    print("time is now",right_now)
    try:
        result = queue.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
        result = None
    if result is not None:
        # code to display the result read from the sensor in tkinter interface goes here
        ...
    # tkinter, not a separate thread, handles this
    root.after(1000, events_every_second)

def one_wire(queue):
    # this is handled in a separate thread, and "does not know" about tkinter at all
    while not stop_reading:
        result = call_to_read_sensor()  # takes 3 seconds
        queue.put(result)
        print("one_wire loop")
        time.sleep(0.1)  # actual call to time.sleep to space sensor readings, if needed.


root = Tk()
stop_reading = False
queue = Queue()
# start events_every_second - tkinter will handle the subsequent calls with the `root.after` scheduling
events_every_second()

thread_one_wire = threading.Thread(target=t_one_wire, args=(queue,))
thread_one_wire.start()


root.mainloop()
```